# Get the value of a column name when column name is a variable using EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Assuming I already have type of shipping I need to find in variables:

```
var categoryLand = ciudad.CategoriaTierra; //string: "A"
var categoryAir = ciudad.CategoriaAvion; //string "G"
```

And that I also have the specific instance of the `ShippingProducto` object I want to use:

```
EFShippingProductoRepository productRepository = new EFShippingProductoRepository();
int convProductId = Convert.ToInt32(productId);
var product = productRepository.FindProductById(convProductId);
```

How can I find the value inside the column named `categoryLand`? For example, if in the code above, `categoryLand` had the value "C", I need to find the value inside of the column `C`.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the property value via reflection:

```
object value = product.GetType().GetProperty(categoryLand).GetValue(product,
```

null);